# How much duty will I have to pay importing 72 bottles of wine from Italy to UK

Tags: united-kingdom, italy, customs

Since leaving the EU the UK now has to pay a customs and excise fee on goods imported into the UK.

Every year my family purchase wine from a vineyard in Italy. This year we will have to pay the UK duty on this wine. I have taken the order and purchased a total of 72 off 750ml bottles this year.
How much duty would I expect to pay?

Comment: Thanks Vicky, didn't know about those tags.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [government](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/rates-and-allowance-excise-duty-alcohol-duty/alcohol-duty-rates-from-24-march-2014) the duty on "still wine exceeding 5.5% - not exceeding 15% abv" is £297.57 per hectolitre, or it other words, £2.9757 per litre (just above £2.23 per bottle).

72 bottles of 750ml contain 54 litres, so a total of £160.69 just for duty.

It may be different if you are talking about sparkling wine or if the alcohol rate is higher or lower, see the other rates listed on the page linked to above.

But remember you'll also have to pay VAT (on the total of wine + shipping + duty).

Also, the shipping company is likely to charge you for the privilege of having to pay taxes and duties. The amount varies a lot depending on the carrier, from nothing to a few dozen pounds.

On the other hand, you should no longer pay VAT to the supplier.

Comment: Thanks JCaron,
This is just what I needed. I had tried to look into this but got completely befuddled with the details I found. Thanks again.